# UITapGestureRecognizer and UIButton

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uibutton, ios6, uitapgesturerecognizer

`UITapGestureRecognizer` and `UIButton` are not working together.

`UIButton` alone is working fine without `UITapGesturerecognizer`. It shows in all scrolling image views but after adding `UITapGestureReconizer` feature it is not showing `UIButton` when tapped.

```
BOOL numberofTaps;
@interface ImageScrollViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, assign) UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer;

- (void)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender;
//////////////////////////
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    UIScrollView *imageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    imageScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    NSInteger numberOfViews = 61;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
        CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
        UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        myButton.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 10, 60, 35);
        [myButton.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [myButton.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
        myButton.layer.borderWidth = 2;
        myButton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
        [myButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        myButton.hidden = YES;

        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", i];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

        UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
        recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [imageView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        recognizer.delegate = self;
        numberofTaps = 1;
        [recognizer release];


        [imageScrollView addSubview:imageView];
        [imageScrollView addSubview:myButton];
     // [imageScrollView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
     // [imageView addSubview:tap];
        [imageView release];
    }
    imageScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:imageScrollView];
    [imageScrollView release];
 }
```

EDIT: **Howcome this works but when i only uncomment myButton.hidden= NO then it works but still doesn't shows my button DONE on the imageviews**

```
- (void)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender {

   // if(numberofTaps == 1){
    CGPoint tapPoint = [sender locationInView:_imageScrollView];
    int tapX = (int) tapPoint.x;
    int tapY = (int) tapPoint.y;
    NSLog(@"TAPPED X:%d Y:%d", tapX, tapY);
//_myButton.hidden = NO;
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" message:@"How are you?" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"I'm awesome." otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
}
```

What is the reason that otherwise it is working but not showing Done UIButton.

Comment: For future questions, please specify a question, and tell us what you have tried to do to solve your problem.

Comment: i tried  recognizer.delegate = self;@property (nonatomic, assign) UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer;UIGestureRecognizerDelegate but no success

Comment: what is not working in this ?`handleTap:` method doesn't call ?

Comment: it did get called but uitapgesturerecognizer seems like not working somehow. when i tap on the imageview it should show hidden uibutton. but it is not showing. i m wondering if m still missing anything important

Comment: can you clear your question ... because if it is being called you cant say that it is not working .... what do you want to do wit this ?

Comment: i simply want when user is going through the images by default uibutton should be hidden but when user taps on uiimage view then uibutton done should be displayed to dismiss the view

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find `button` which you have to show. So for that you will have to `setTag:` on your `UIButton` before adding them to `scrollView`

like this -

```
myButton.tag = i;
```

Then add tag to your `UIImageView` also before adding them to `scrollView` like this -

```
 imageView.tag = i*100;
```

Now in `handleTap:` method you can compare tags and can get the button which you have to show.

```
-(void)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender 
{
    //getting all buttons of scrollView
    for(UIButton *button in scrollView.subviews)
    {
       //comparing tags
       if(button.tag == sender.view.tag/100)
       {
           button.hidden = NO;
       }
    }
}
```

Do this, remove your if Condition.

Comment: how come this works but my button doesn't shows - (void)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender {
       
   // if(numberofTaps == 1){
    CGPoint tapPoint = [sender locationInView:_imageScrollView];
    int tapX = (int) tapPoint.x;
    int tapY = (int) tapPoint.y;
    NSLog(@"TAPPED X:%d Y:%d", tapX, tapY);
    //_myButton.hidden = NO;
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" message:@"How are you?" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"I'm awesome." otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    }